# Get error messages in django_rest_framework in a json format

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-custom-user

I want to get an error message

```
{
    "phone": [
        "user with this phone already exists."
    ]
}
```

in a JSON format like `{"error": "user with this phone already exists."}`
from the response

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "phone": [
        "user with this phone already exists."
    ]
}
```

but what I am getting is just `VM8:1 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/ 400 (Bad Request)`
Here is my code:

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'stream', 'school', "password", )
```

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone'), max_length=15, unique=True)
    stream = models.CharField(_('stream'), max_length=25)
    school =  models.CharField(_('school'), max_length=40)
    tests_given = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), null=True, blank=True)
    messages = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100), null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    is_staff =models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
    
    def __str__(self) :
        return f"{self.first_name}"
```

[Here is what I get from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfmna.png)
and [and its what I get from browser when I call an API from react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb0Fh.png)

Comment: Can you please show your model ?

Comment: Also what is the error message you get now ?

Comment: I improved my question. Now you @erfanmorsali can also have a look.

Comment: The default error is also a valid json. Either you have an parse it in frontend or customize the validation if you like to get in that exact structure.

Comment: yeah I got it. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is how you can achieve it -

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

    def post(self, request):
    
       serializer = UserCreateSerializer(request.data, many=False)
    
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
           
        try:
    
        serializer.save()
           
        except IntegrityError:
    
            return Response({"error":"User with this phone already exists."}, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
    
        return Response("msg":"User created.", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Your `User` model will raise an `IntegrityError` exception if the provided value for `phone` already exist in the db table. You can handle this by putting `serializer.save()` in a `try.. catch` block.

You can use this code in your `views.py`.

Answer (score -1):

Add raise_exception=True in serializer.is_valid() in your views

```
def post(self, request):
   serializer = UserCreateSerializer(request.data, many=False)
   if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
   return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```